# I want to stream video from my webserver, but I only want it to stream when there is a viewer

Tags: javascript, video, stream

This might seam like a really stupid question.  I'm trying to set up a webcam to watch my fish while I'm away, and I want it to be on all the time, however, I have a bandwidth cap, so I can't have it streaming all the time.  I was hoping to develop some sort of application where it will start streaming whenever a user connects and cease streaming whenever the user disconnects.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Page Visibility API](http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/).

Supported Browsers : http://caniuse.com/#feat=pagevisibility

Comment: This looks great.  I'll definitely be looking into this. Thanks!